# Separation of multiple tables in the same row

Tags: tables

To save paper space, I want to split a table into 3 identical rows.
This works fine, but I want to separate each of the three parts with a vertical double line without any crossing. Unfortunately I did not find a way, how to remove the crossings (you can see them in the picture)

```
  \begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c || c | c | c || c | c |c | }
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Symbol}} } &
    \multicolumn{2}{ c||}{\textbf{Probability}} &     
    \multicolumn{1}{ c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Symbol}} } &
    \multicolumn{2}{ c||}{\textbf{Probability}}  &    
    \multicolumn{1}{ c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Symbol}} } &
    \multicolumn{2}{ c|}{\textbf{Probability}} \\  \cline{2-3} \cline{5-6} \cline{8-9} 
    &  \textbf{abs.} & \textbf{rel. [\%]} &
    &  \textbf{abs.} & \textbf{rel. [\%]}  &
    &  \textbf{abs.} & \textbf{rel. [\%]} \\ \hline    
    A & 22 &   8.16 & J & 3  &  0.16  & S & 34 &  6.32 \\
    B & 104 &  1.49 & K & 58 &  0.77  & T & 33 &  9.05 \\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
```

[image]

Can someone please help me to get rid of these crossings?

Comment: you could use `hhline` package or simpler and perhaps better just set it as three `tabular` with a space between each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with `hhline` and `cellspace`, which adds a minimal vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` (or `C` if you load `siunitx`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hhline, multirow, array, cellspace}
 \setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{3pt}
 \setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{3pt}

\begin{document}

{\setlength{\doublerulesep}{1em}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{ | Sc | Sc | Sc |}}
\hhline{---||---||---}
        \multicolumn{1}{|Sc|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Symbol}} } &
    \multicolumn{2}{Sc||}{\textbf{Probability}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{Sc|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Symbol}} } &
    \multicolumn{2}{Sc||}{\textbf{Probability}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{Sc|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Symbol}} } &
    \multicolumn{2}{Sc|}{\textbf{Probability}} \\ 
\hhline{|~|--||~|--||~|--}
    & \textbf{abs.} & \textbf{rel. [\%]} &
    & \textbf{abs.} & \textbf{rel. [\%]} &
    & \textbf{abs.} & \textbf{rel. [\%]} \\
\hhline{---||---||---}
    A & 22 & 8.16 & J & 3 & 0.16 & S & 34 & 6.32 \\
    B & 104 & 1.49 & K & 58 & 0.77 & T & 33 & 9.05 \\
\hhline{---||---||---}
\end{tabular}}

\end{document}
```

[image]